# RMI Multilevel in Same Program

Tags: java, rmi

i am tying to serially invoke Java RMI from server to other server ?

RMI Client 1 >--(1)--->RMI Server 1 >---(2)-----> RMI Server 2

Means on RMI Client 1 will invoke method on RMI Server 1 and that RMI server 1 will invoke method on Other RMI Server 2 acting client..for RMI Server 2 in same execution program

Exception : **java.lang.ClassCastException: rmiserver1_Stub cannot be cast to interfc2**

Please Help..

Code Here :

**rmiserver1.java**

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


class rmiserver1 extends UnicastRemoteObject implements interfc1
{
public rmiserver1() throws RemoteException
{
    System.out.println("RMIServer 1 Constructor ");
}


public String remote1() 
{
    System.out.println("here Calling RMIServer2 method remote2 ");
                try
                {
//here is Exception
                    interfc2 obj2=(interfc2) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/rmiserver2");
                    String r2=obj2.remote2();
                    System.out.println("Result from rmiserver2 :"+r2);
                }
                catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    return "RMIServer1 remote 1 method return here....";

}


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("RMIServer 1 Main method ");

    try
            {
                rmiserver1 p1=new rmiserver1();
                    Naming.rebind("rmiserver1",p1);

            System.out.println("RMIServer 1 rebinded ");

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

}
 }
```

**interfc1.java**

```
 import java.rmi.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;

public interface interfc1 extends Remote
{
public String remote1() throws RemoteException;
}
```

**interfc2.java**

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public interface interfc2 extends Remote
{
public String remote2() throws RemoteException;
}
```

**rmiserver2.java**

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


class rmiserver2 extends UnicastRemoteObject implements interfc2
{
public rmiserver2() throws RemoteException
{
    System.out.println("RMIServer 2 Constructor ");
}


public String remote2() 
{
    return "RMIServer2 remote 2 method return here....";
}


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("RMIServer 2 Main method ");

    try
            {
                rmiserver1 p1=new rmiserver1();
                    Naming.rebind("rmiserver2",p1);

            System.out.println("RMIServer 2 rebinded ");

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

}
}
```

**rmiclient1.java**

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;



class rmiclient1  
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("RMIClient 1 Main method");

    try
    {
        interfc1 obj1=(interfc1) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/rmiserver1");
        String r1=obj1.remote1();
        System.out.println("Result from rmiserver1 :"+r1);
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
}
```

**Exception on rmiserver1 prompt :**

```
  java.lang.ClassCastException: rmiserver1_Stub cannot be cast to interfc2
    at rmiserver1.remote1(rmiserver1.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
 sorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:305)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:5
 35)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTranspor
 t.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport
 .java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExec
 utor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Please Help me.....

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the main method of your class `rmiserver2`, you are binding `rmiserver1` with the name "rmiserver2".

Your current code in the main method of `rmiserver2`

```
rmiserver1 p1=new rmiserver1();
                Naming.rebind("rmiserver2",p1);
```

What you wanted was this :

```
rmiserver2 p2=new rmiserver2();
                Naming.rebind("rmiserver2",p1);
```

Looks like a copy paste issue :)

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if it worked for you, thats how SO works :)